# stb_truetype.h processing unicode

Tags: c, unicode, truetype

I am trying to render chinese characters using `stb_truetype.h`. Yet the chinese character  was rendered wrongly. I tried to render an English character like 'a' with no problem. Can anyone provide some insight on how to process unicode on ubuntu 13.04/gcc4.8.1 ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define STB_TRUETYPE_IMPLEMENTATION  // force following include to generate implementation
#include "stb_truetype.h"

char ttf_buffer[1<<25];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   stbtt_fontinfo font;
   unsigned char *bitmap;
   int w,h,i,j,c = (argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0x4e00)/*choose character here*/, s = (argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 20/*set font size*/);

   fread(ttf_buffer, 1, 1<<25, fopen(argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "mingliu.ttc", "rb"));
   //c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf
   //also tried Dejavu font on ubuntu for the chinese character
   stbtt_InitFont(&font, ttf_buffer, stbtt_GetFontOffsetForIndex(ttf_buffer,0));

       bitmap = stbtt_GetCodepointBitmap(&font, 0,stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight(&font, s), c, &w, &h, 0,0);

       for (j=0; j < h; ++j) {
          for (i=0; i < w; ++i)
             putchar(" 1234567"[bitmap[j*w+i]>>5]);
          putchar('\n');
       }

   return 0;
}
```

output using 'a'

```
  2342   
 52  61  
 7   32  
 1   43  
   2553  
  53 33  
 62  33  
26   43  
271 165  
 7763174 
  2   1
```

output using'一'

```
466666666666666664
653333333333333356
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
63              36
664444444444444466
466666666666666664
```

which should be look like this:
[image: character 'one']
from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4e00/index.htm

Comment: Please provide the command line arguments, as it is not clear from your code what you are using. Does it work with plain Arial and a large(ish) Unicode? The doc mentions "Todo: non-MS cmaps" Not behind my computer right now but I can check if that could be the issue with mingliu.ttc.

Comment: At least on c:/windows, it is common for a glyph that's not available in a font to be rendered as a rectangle.  That sure looks like a rectangle :)  The code is unnecessarily cryptic, mistaking U+6211 for decimal 6211 and you've got an explanation, that's not a valid glyph in MingLiU.

Comment: @Jongware I should be compiling like `gcc sample.c -lm`,but I will check when I get to home.
@HansPassant As far as I know , I should be using the correct codepoint, which is character 'one' in Chinese. I am suspecting gcc use something other than UTF-8?

Answer (score 4):

If you provide the right unicode key for symbol - the problem is most likely that your font does not support the specified char. Font files may vary from each other and actual symbols may be missing. I use the following code to check if the char is really supported and not substituted by some default frame symbol:

```
// 11111 - code of some definitely unsupported char in my case
int replacer = stbtt_FindGlyphIndex(&font->font, 11111);     
int g = stbtt_FindGlyphIndex(&font->font, codepoint);
if (g == replacer)
    return NULL;
```

So you can compare glyph index with glyph index of some definitely unsupported symbol (you can select your own) and check if symbol is really present inside font file.